# R - How to set the range of the colorscale in a hexbin plot

Tags: r, matrix, scatter-plot, lattice

I am making a scatter plot matrix using hexbin plots to show the density of certain areas.

Example:

```
library(lattice)
library(hexbin)
splom(cbind(rnorm(10000),rnorm(10000),rnorm(100),rnorm(100)), 
      ,varnames = c("A","B","C","D")
      ,panel = panel.hexbinplot
      ,lower.panel = function(x, y, ...) {
          panel.fill(col = brewer.pal(9, "Greys")[ round(cor(x, y,method =  "spearman") * 4 + 2)])
      cpl <- current.panel.limits()
      panel.text(mean(cpl$xlim), mean(cpl$ylim), round(cor(x, y,method = "spearman"),2), font=2)
  }
  ,upper.panel = function(x, y, ...){
      panel.hexbinplot(x, y, type = "r", xbins = 10, ...)
  }
  ,pscale=0, varname.cex=1, xlab = ""
)
```

It seems to me, that the colorscale, i.e. which count applies to which color, is recalculated in each of the 6 hexbin plots. It doesn't make a difference here but it does in my data. How can I set all these to ONE scale, meaning that a hexagon with 25 counts has the same color in all 6 plots, no matter if the maximum count in the plot is 25 or 150.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try setting `colorcount=17` in `panel.hexbinplot`. The documentation for that parameter can be found in `?gplot.hexbin`. With your example with random data it's difficult to tell if it actually works.

Comment: I suppose you meant `colorcut`? I didn't find `colorcount`. Colorcut is not working. I edited the working example. It now contains way more points in some cells than in others and still the color range is the same in all of them.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, and you are also right that it doesn't work. I'm not sure why panel.hexbin insists on normalizing the counts to 0-1 for each panel rather than tracking total counts.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late, but if somebody else is having the same question...Try using the argument ***maxcnt***, it worked for me using the package Opeanair. I generated 4 plots and every one has the same color ramp: the hexagons with the same number of counts have the same color.